# Issue with Recognizing Kotlin Multiplatform Package in Swift Package Manager

Tags: ios, swift, kotlin-multiplatform, swift-package-manager

I've encountered an issue while working with a Kotlin Multiplatform (KMP) project and Swift Package Manager (SPM). I have a simple dummy KMP Swift Package available at [this repository](https://github.com/atonamy/kmp-spm-example).

The goal is to use this package in another Swift project managed by SPM, which can be found [here](https://github.com/atonamy/spm-kmp-example).

The process begins smoothly with the command `swift build`:

```
Fetching https://github.com/atonamy/kmp-spm-example.git from cache
Fetched https://github.com/atonamy/kmp-spm-example.git (0.89s)
Computing version for https://github.com/atonamy/kmp-spm-example.git
Computed https://github.com/atonamy/kmp-spm-example.git at 0.0.1 (1.07s)
Creating working copy for https://github.com/atonamy/kmp-spm-example.git
Working copy of https://github.com/atonamy/kmp-spm-example.git resolved at 0.0.1
Building for debugging..
[2/2] Emitting module TestSPM
Build complete! (7.97s)
```

However, if I change the command with this new command:

```
swift build -Xswiftc "-sdk" -Xswiftc "`xcrun --sdk iphonesimulator --show-sdk-path`" -Xswiftc "-target" -Xswiftc "arm64-apple-ios16.4-simulator"
```

I'll stumble with this weird error:

```
     Sources/TestSPM/TestSPM.swift:2:8: error: no such module 'spm'
import spm
```

Interestingly, when I integrate the same package into a regular .xcodeproj, it functions correctly without any issues (with target ios16.4-simulator). This leads me to wonder why it fails to be recognized when used within a SPM project.

Has anyone else experienced this, or does anyone have insights on why this might be happening and how to resolve it?